# Why does one background thread have the same thread id as the main service thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

Trying to create 2 background threads and sending a message from thread0 to thread1 where it
 is handled by MessageHandler using the *android* Looper and message queue associated with thread1.

I expected to see separate thread ids for threads 0,1 and the main thread. However, I was surprised to see something unexpected.

```
09-08 14:23:21.089: D/MQ(4514): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 2:23:21 PM
09-08 14:23:21.099: V/MQ(4514): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 14:23:21.099: V/MQ(4514): BackgroundThread0. Thread id = 280 sent message 0
09-08 14:23:21.099: V/MQ(4514): MessageHandler on thread Thread id = 1 received message 0
```

Why does BackgroundThread1 have the same thread id as the main service thread id = 1?

I install it from Eclipse using Run As, and am starting it in a windows console window:

```
D:\>adb shell am startservice --user 0 -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n "com.sandbox.mq/.MainService"
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.sandbox.mq/.MainService }
```

--
package com.sandbox.mq;

```
public class StartMainService extends Application {
    final static String TAG = "MQ";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Log.d(TAG, "Hi, the system is up! Today is: " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

--

```
public class MainService extends Service {
    final static String TAG = "MQ";
    BackgroundThread0 bthread0;
    BackgroundThread1 bthread1;

    public class MqBinder extends Binder {
        public MqBinder(Context ctxt) {
            Log.v(TAG, "MqBinder() " + "Thread id = "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return new MqBinder(this);
    }

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE "
        + "Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
bthread1 = new BackgroundThread1();
if (!bthread1.isAlive()) {
    bthread1.start();
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(). bthread1 was already started");
}
bthread0 = new BackgroundThread0();
if (!bthread0.isAlive()) {
    bthread0.start();
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(). bthread0 was already started");
}       
return START_STICKY;
}

    private class BackgroundThread0 extends Thread {
        Handler b1Handler;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            b1Handler = bthread1.b1Handler;
            Message msg = b1Handler.obtainMessage(MessageHandler.TYPE0);
            b1Handler.sendMessage(msg);
            Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundThread0. " + "Thread id = "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " sent message "
                    + msg.what);
        }

    }

    private class BackgroundThread1 extends Thread {
        public BackgroundThread1() {
            super();
            b1Handler = new MessageHandler();
        }

        Handler b1Handler;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Looper.prepare();
            Looper.loop();
        }

    }

    private static class MessageHandler extends Handler {
        static final int TYPE0 = 0;
        static final int TYPE1 = 1;
        static final int TYPE2 = 2;

        public MessageHandler() {

        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.v(TAG, "MessageHandler on thread " + "Thread id = "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " received message "
                    + msg.what);

            switch (msg.what) {
            case TYPE0:
                break;
            case TYPE1:
                break;
            case TYPE2:
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sandbox.mq" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:name="com.sandbox.mq.StartMainService"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name="com.sandbox.mq.MainService" android:exported="true"> 
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>          
        </service>        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

From eclipse, **DDMS** window

```
1   4514    Native  0   2   main    
*2  4518    VmWait  0   0   GC  
*3  4519    VmWait  0   0   Signal Catcher  
*4  4520    Runnable    0   2   JDWP    
*5  4521    VmWait  0   0   Compiler    
*6  4522    Wait    0   0   ReferenceQueueDaemon    
*7  4523    Wait    0   0   FinalizerDaemon 
*8  4524    Wait    0   0   FinalizerWatchdogDaemon 
9   4525    Native  0   0   Binder_1    
10  4526    Native  0   0   Binder_2    
11  4527    Native  0   0   Thread-279
```

**After following TacBoss suggestion below, I get thread id=450 which is expected. thread id 451 likely completed.**

```
1   11756   Native  1   1   main    
*2  11760   VmWait  0   0   GC  
*3  11761   VmWait  0   0   Signal Catcher  
*4  11762   Runnable    0   0   JDWP    
*5  11763   VmWait  0   0   Compiler    
*6  11764   Wait    0   0   ReferenceQueueDaemon    
*7  11765   Wait    0   0   FinalizerDaemon 
*8  11766   Wait    0   0   FinalizerWatchdogDaemon 
9   11767   Native  0   0   Binder_1    
10  11768   Native  0   0   Binder_2    
11  11770   Native  0   0   Thread-450  


09-08 15:06:05.089: D/MQ(7931): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:06:05 PM
09-08 15:06:05.089: V/MQ(7931): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:06:06.149: D/MQ(7946): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:06:06 PM
09-08 15:06:06.149: V/MQ(7946): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:06:10.269: D/MQ(7964): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:06:10 PM
09-08 15:06:10.269: V/MQ(7964): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:06:26.339: D/MQ(8110): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:06:26 PM
09-08 15:06:26.339: V/MQ(8110): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:06:36.319: D/MQ(8166): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:06:36 PM
09-08 15:06:36.319: V/MQ(8166): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:06:37.389: D/MQ(8182): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:06:37 PM
09-08 15:06:37.389: V/MQ(8182): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:06:41.469: D/MQ(8200): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:06:41 PM
09-08 15:06:41.469: V/MQ(8200): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:08:27.439: D/MQ(8577): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:08:27 PM
09-08 15:08:27.439: V/MQ(8577): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:08:28.479: D/MQ(8593): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:08:28 PM
09-08 15:08:28.489: V/MQ(8593): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:08:32.579: D/MQ(8612): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:08:32 PM
09-08 15:08:32.579: V/MQ(8612): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:08:48.679: D/MQ(8630): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:08:48 PM
09-08 15:08:48.679: V/MQ(8630): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:29:00.949: D/MQ(11756): Hi, the system is up! Today is: Sep 8, 2014 3:29:00 PM
09-08 15:29:00.949: V/MQ(11756): onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE Thread id = 1
09-08 15:29:00.959: V/MQ(11756): BackgroundThread0. Thread id = 451 sent message 0
09-08 15:29:00.959: V/MQ(11756): MessageHandler on thread Thread id = 450 received message 0
```

--code changes

```
    private class BackgroundThread1 extends Thread {
        public BackgroundThread1() {
            super();
            start();
        }

        Handler b1Handler;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Looper.prepare();
            Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
            b1Handler = new MessageHandler(looper);
            Looper.loop();
        }

    }

        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(). I am INSIDE THE main sERVICE "
                + "Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        bthread1 = new BackgroundThread1();
//      if (!bthread1.isAlive()) {
//          bthread1.start();
//      } else {
//          Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(). bthread1 was already started");
//      }
        bthread0 = new BackgroundThread0();
        if (!bthread0.isAlive()) {
            bthread0.start();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(). bthread0 was already started");
        }       
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: Try to paste the thread list from the debug view

Comment: @TacB0sS good idea! I posted it above with fresh output. Also I was instantiating thread0, then 1 - a bug. Now I am creating threads 1, then 0. The original question still remains, though

Comment: It doesn't look like you have the same thread with the same ID or Name

Comment: @TacB0sS true. I ran the console command to start service and then clicked on DDMS window and the Update Threads button and the package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this didn't pop straight up...

the problem is you create the handler within the constructor of the BGThread1 and this code is called from the main thread! and that is why the handler queue is also attached to the main thread.

```
public BackgroundThread1() {
    super();
    b1Handler = new MessageHandler(); // this is the main thread here...
}
```

if you want this handler to run on another thread you first have to do something like this:

```
private class BackgroundThread1 extends HandlerThread {
    public BackgroundThread1() {
        super();
         ...
          Some code
         ...
        start();
        b1Handler = new MessageHandler(getLooper()); 
            // this is the main thread here... but you create the handler with the looper of the new thread!
    }
    ...
}
```

This would create the thread in the context you expect it to.

===================================================

An example of extending a "regular" thread:

```
class MyThread
        extends Thread {

    private Handler myHandler;

    public MyThread() {
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
        myHandler = new Handler(looper);
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Now the handler runs on the new thread.

Comment: Can you please show how to do it extending Thread and not HandlerThread?

Comment: you wrote `BackgroundThread1 extends HandlerThread`. how can we do it with `BackgroundThread1 extends Thread`?

Comment: excellent - that is the solution. But why is onStartCommand() called so many times now? See trace in question above.

Comment: From what it looks like the your Application is recreated over and over... are you sure the prints match the code you posted?

Comment: yes, my code matches. I am on Windows 7, android 4.4, Nexus 5. Can you please run it on your android device to see if you get the same?

Comment: From what it looks like, something is killing your app and starting it over and over again. the application.onCreate() should only be called once per lifecycle of the application. What I can't be sure

Comment: I am returning START_STICKY

Comment: anyway, that question is unanswered but you gave me the correct solution which I accept.

Comment: in your other solution `BackgroundThread1 extends HandlerThread` you did start() in the constructor. I found it is not necessary to do it here - one must do it outside. Also, I put `b1Handler = new MessageHandler(getLooper()); ` in overridden method, `onLooperPrepared()`

Comment: it was just an example... to fit your implementation...technically you can call start from wherever you like, but architecturally speaking it is wrong, because a thread should not decide it own life cycle, but some sort of a manager or a queue if you like are responsible for its lifecycle

Comment: One detail you may wish to add to the part of your answer extending HandlerThread - if you agree. getLooper() `If this thread has been started, this method will block until the looper has been initialized` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html. If you had not called start() before the getLooper(), it would not have returned the looper of the new thread - is this statement correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Service` lifecycle is handled on the main thread, that is : `Service` methods like `onCreate`, `onStartCommand`, `onDestruction` are called on the main thread by default, as explained in the second paragraph of [android.app.Service's Class Overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process.

Comment: Did you read the question? I am talking of 3 threads. 0,1,main

Comment: Yes i read. The answer you accepted says the same thing i am, that is : because the log statement is inside `Service.onCreate` it is normal that the printed thread id is 1. Besides, 1 is usually the id of the main thread, so speaking of thread '0, 1, main' is confusing.

Comment: the log statement is inside handleMessage() which was meant to run inside thread1.